# Promela Syntax error

Tags: spin, promela

I am receiving a syntax error when I attempt to run my promela code, the error says Error: syntax error saw 'token: ::'

which is referring to this line of code (lines 10-13):

```
#define IniRunning(x,y) if
                    :: ((x==A) && (y==B)) -> IniRunningAB = 1
                    :: else skip
                    fi
```

I have tried to add a semi colon after the if and also after the fi but the error doesn't seem to go away.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `\` before each line break in the macro definition.

You can check the intermediate text (after macro expansion) with
`spin -I check.pml`